# Is it possible to use ajax to deliver ad content to publishers of an ad network

Tags: javascript, ajax, ads, advertisement-server

I'm developing an ad network for my project.

Is it possible to use ajax to deliver ad content to publishers of an ad network ?

I already know google uses document.write or something similar like this.

```js
document.write('<iframe src="http://myadserver.com/showads.php?ad_client='+ ad_client+'&ad_slot='+ad_slot+' margin=0 frameborder=0 scrolling=no allowtransparency=true ></iframe>');
```

But what about ajax ?

Can I use ajax to deliver ad content to the publishers on my ad network ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sure can. Just import some JS file into your document and have it alter your page to display your ad.
First load the file, with whatever parameters you choose to indicate what ad to load, the container name or whatever you need. You should also provide a callback function for the script to call once loaded that displays the ad.

```
function changeAd(adURL)
{
   adContainer.innerHTML="<img src=\""+adURL+"\" />";
}
var adScript = document.createElement("script");
    adScript.type = "text/javascript";
    adScript.src = "http://yoursite/adScript.js?someparam=1";
document.head.append(adScript);
```

The contents of `adScript` should just call `changeAd` with the URL to your ad.

```
changeAd("http://yoursite.com/ads/fancyad.jpg");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is a great help for me. Thnaks. But this is not ajax. Am I wrong ? If I'm correct Is it possible to use ajax for this ?

Comment: This is asynchronous javascript. If you stick to the acronym definition of Ajax, it would need to use XML. The problem is that since you are trying to load your ads from a different domain, you would not be able to load your ads URL from an XML file, due to cross domain restrictions. I think this solution would be called Ajax in the more general definition of the term and, as far as I know, any other working solution would be a variation of this.

Comment: OK OK. I'm not aware of that before but I felt there are some issues with that. But I didn't know what are the issues. Now I have an idea about that because of your help. Thanks a lot. I got what i was expected. Thanks.